# Ajax request type POST returning GET

Tags: ajax, django, post

I'm currently trying to make an ajax POST request to send a testimonial simple form to a Django view. The problem is this request is returning a GET instead of a POST.

This is my ajax:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form.testimonial-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataString = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/testimonials",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(_data) {        
        if (_data[0]){
          $('.modal-text').css({display: "none"});
        }
        else{
          $('.unsuccess').css({display: "block"});
        }
       }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

replace `type` by `method`

```
method: 'post',
```

also you may need send `headers`:

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': getCSRFToken()
},
```

where `getCSRFToken` is:

```
function getCSRFToken() {
    return $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
}
```

Comment: it sends post to your view and I don't see which request type returns your view, so how I can help you? show your views, or even better read docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example here is example how you can send json response

Comment: or if it sends GET to your view there are many similar questions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form and if it sends GET -this is strictly jquery question, so no needs to add django tag

Comment: @madzohan (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ``$.ajax();`` does NOT have ``method`` attribute. it is ``type``

Comment: @doniyor hm I see, but it works for me with jquery-1.11.1,  it is in my head from MooTools :D

Comment: @doniyor https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/598ed050f6931922214aeaea8a1dc867e0cc6fb7/src/ajax.js#L503 anyway it is the same :P

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why this is happening, but i would write the function in a bit different way. since `ajax();`'s default `type` is `"GET"`, i suspect somewhere it is being set to default.

first set the `type="button"` of submit button (whose id is e.g. `"submit_button_id"`), so it doesnot submits if you click on it. or put the button outside of `<form>`

then try this code

```
<script>
$(function(){ // same as "$(document).ready(function()".. 
  $("#submit_button_id").on('click',function(){

  var dataString = $('form.testimonial-form').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/testimonials",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(_data) {        
      if (_data[0]){
        $('.modal-text').css({display: "none"});
      }
      else{
        $('.unsuccess').css({display: "block"});
      }
     }
   });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It didnt work... Once I do "print request.is_ajax()" on my testimonials view I get "True" and I also do "print request.method" I get "GET".